# Always login Frame - HTML Cookies

Tags: html, cookies

i want to build a website with following features:
2 Frames. 
1 Frame with am edit box and a button.
The second frame should show a page whitch is secured by username/password. 
Is there a possibility that a sepcified user is always logged on?
The problem is: I can't edit any thing on the page of the second frame.

I have to use this in the office and have to see the orders of a webshop backend. But the user who monitors the orders should use this website without login. Is it possible to store the username/password on  a local maschine and login automaticly and permanent(i DONT mean a password manager).

The workflow is: Open the local HTML file and see the two frames.
Any idea. I hope i could figure out what I have to do.

Comment: Maybe with jquery and:
http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post

I tried:
   $.post("http://www.foobar.com/login.php", { email_address: "foobar@foo.com", password: "123456" } ); 


But don't work

Comment: If the system is checking things like the referrer/cookies using an AJAX post this way may not work out.

Comment: http://nopaste.info/120d3d313a.html
This is the login.php

Comment: @SurfingCat the login code seems pretty straight forward... as long as the right URL is accessed, and the username/password are sent as post params (and they validate) user is logged in.  You don't get redirected due to lack of cookies? or a failed login message?

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried a few hours and the fault was by the "boss", he killed silently a part of the backend. :-D 
This unsecure(!) version works very well. I found a possibility to reduce the rights of the auto-login user to the one needet file. 
THANK YOU VERY MUCH @ll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give the "manager" person a real login in the system that provides a read-only view.

If the system can't do that, I'd recommend fixing the system... but it sounds like you are stuck with the system as is and can not alter it.

**update(s):**
(updated again to do a post vs. get)

Based on the comments below, here's a basic sample of the *insecure* auto-login:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>CEO System Overview</title>
    <script>
      function autoLogin(){
        document.forms['auto'].submit();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="autoLogin();">
    <form name="auto" method="post" target="overview" action="fullpath/foobar.php/login.php/action/process">
      <input type="hidden" name="email_address" value="foo@bar.com"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="password" value="foobar"/>
    </form>
    <iframe name="overview" width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0"
      src="about:blank">
    </iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Notes:

1. This is ***insecure*** - any user of this PC/file can access the system
2. Navigation via the browser back/forward buttons may be a bit messed up (some browsers handle navigation within iframes better than others)

Comment: I know I know but the ceo want a quickn dirty version.
This is not possible

Comment: will the system you are trying to access in the iframe accept a login request via GET?  e.g. can you just build a page that sets the initial URL of the iframe to: `theLoginPage.php?usr=ceo&pass=kittens`  it would be HIGHLY insecure... but if the boss wants... (POST can work too, it just depends how "picky" the login page is)

Comment: Its a post login to a gambio webshop:
<form id="login" action="https://www.foobar.php/login.php/action/process" method="post">

Comment: login.php?email_address=foo@bar.com&password=foobar

Wont work

Answer (score 1):

If you login at least once -- maybe you could use JS or a client-side script to alter the existing cookie to expire later -- since you want forever, about 10 years should do the trick, haha.